# Understanding differential form of a manifold embedded in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, submanifold

In Example 16.9 of John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds 2nd edition, the following 2-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ was considered:
$$
w=x dy \wedge dz + y dz \wedge dx + z dx \wedge dy. 
$$
The example then considered the integration
$$
\int_M \omega
$$
on the manifold $M\subset{\mathbb{R}^3}$ which is the 2-sphere with radius 1.

My question is: wouldn't the integral only make sense if $\omega$ were a differential form on $M$ according to the definition? Here $\omega$ is defined on the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I could only make sense of it in the following way.  Take the first term $x dy\wedge dz$ as an example.
Consider the coordinate charts
$$\varphi_1: U=\{(y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y^2+z^2<1 \} \mapsto M_1=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3, x^2+y^2+z^2=1, x>0 \},\\ \varphi_1(y,z)=(\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2},y,z)$$ and
$$\varphi_2: U=\{(y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y^2+z^2<1 \} \mapsto M_2=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3, x^2+y^2+z^2=1, x<0 \},   \\ \varphi_2(y,z)=(-\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2},y,z).$$

Then I view $x dy \wedge dz$ as the sum of the corresponding two 2-forms on $M_1$ and $M_2$ represented by these two charts.

However this understanding seems a bit cumbersome. I saw a number of similar examples where  a differential form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is introduced  but is then integrated over a manifold $M \subset\mathbb{R}^n$. I wonder if there is a simple understanding that I have missed.

Comment: It really means $\int_M \iota^* \omega$, where $\iota : M \to \mathbb R^3$ is the inclusion (which is smooth since $M$ is a submanifold).

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks! That makes sense.